# A riddle in java - Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

My friend gave me a riddle to solve. It goes like this:

> There are 100 people. Each one of them, in his turn, does the following:
>
> The first person opens all the boxes. The second person change the
>   state to all the boxes whose number is divided by 2, without
>   remainders. For instance, if a box is open and its number is divided
>   by 2, it is closed. The same goes for a closed box.
>
> The third person change the state to all the boxes whose number is
>   divided by 3, without remainders. The "i" person change the state to
>   all the boxes whose number is divided by i, without remainders.
>
> Now, at then end of the process, I need to display all the boxes(their
>   numbers) who are open.

I tried to implement a solution but I think it's not efficient. Here it is:

```
public class BoxesExc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box[] boxes = new Box[100];
        // Inflating the array with boxes
        for(int i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
            boxes[i] = new Box(i, false);
        }

        // Main part:
        for(int i=1; i<=boxes.length; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
                // If the number is even
                if(i%2 == 0) {
                    if(j%i == 0) {
                        boxes[j].setOpen(!boxes[j].isOpen);
                    }
                } 
                // If the number is odd
                else {
                    if(j%2 != 0) {
                        if(j%i == 0) {
                            boxes[j].setOpen(!boxes[j].isOpen);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    //Displaying the opened boxes:
    for(Box box : boxes) {
        if(box.isOpen)
            System.out.println(box.getNum()+",");
    }
    }

    public static class Box {
        private int num;
        private boolean isOpen;

        public Box(int num, boolean isOpen) {
            this.isOpen = isOpen;
        }

        public int getNum() {
            return num;
        }

        public boolean isOpen() {
            return isOpen;
        }

        public void setOpen(boolean isOpen) {
            this.isOpen = isOpen;
        }

    }
}
```

I haven't tried that yet but I just by looking at it, it looks awful.
I need your help guys with finding a better solution.

EDIT: Alright guys I managed to solve this. Here is the solution:

```
public class BoxesExc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] boxes = new int[101];
        // Inflating the array with boxes
        for(int i=1; i<boxes.length; i++) {
            boxes[i] = i;
        }

        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<boxes.length; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
                if(i%j == 0)
                    counter++;
            }
            if(counter%2 != 0)
                System.out.print(""+i+", ");
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is based on a famous question. A little research on "light bulb switching brain teaser" will help

Comment: an example: `12` is divisible by `2, 3, 4, 6, 12`. It will be closed. What you are searching for here is the parity of the number of divisors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, njzk2. Do you have any recommendations on how to do that? I think it's a good idea

Comment: I would typically do that in 3 steps : step 1, create an array to count the divisors, then loop i = 1-100 and loop again to increment all `n*i` (1,2,3,..., 2,4,6,..., 3,6,9,...) step 2, loop on that array, and test the parity of the divisor count. step 3, display.

Comment: then you can merge step 1 and step 2, instead of counting divisor, just invert a boolean value.

Comment: Your `Box` is passive - think about processing a message 'change'. Provide a useful `toString()`. I see a constructor demanding a parameter `num` - and ignoring it - think about numbering `Box`es automatically (and about concurrency). You might model `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

it has very simple solution

> the boxes which will be opened will be all the boxes which thier place is square exponentiation of a number.

for example in your question its between 1-100 so the answer will be:

> 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100

also my solution is faster than yours because its order is θ(√n)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all the boxes and modulate by your current indices. Do a switch to set the box open or closed depending on it's previous state. Then after you're done doing the 100 loop; do a secondary loop through the 100 boxes to see which ones are open and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation of what I described in the comment:

```
public class BoxesExc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box[] boxes = new Box[100];
        // Inflating the array with boxes
        for(int i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
            boxes[i] = new Box(i, false);
        }

        // Main part:
        for (int i=1; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            // j+=i goes 3,6,9... for i = 3
            for (int j = i; j < boxes.length; j+=i) {
                 boxes[j].setOpen(!boxes[j].isOpen);
            }
        }

        //Displaying the opened boxes:
        for(Box box : boxes) {
            if(box.isOpen)
                System.out.println(box.getNum()+",");
        }
    }
}
```

Nota: you can init the box status to `open` and skip the first iteration (start with `i = 2`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to print the numbers, I think following is enough:

```
public class BoxesExc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int boxNum = 100;
        for(int i = 1; i*i <= boxNum; i++) {
            System.out.print(i*i+",");
        }
    }
}
```